# Mouse click while screen turned off

Tags: mouse, screen, remote-desktop, click

I have an iMac 2013 with Catalina.
I need to turn off the screen and continue able to clicking the mouse with AnyDesk/AppleScript.
But when I turn off the screen, I can move the mouse but clicking does not work.

Comment: Can you explain how you are "turning off the screen"?

Comment: pmset displaysleepnow
or shift+ctrl+eject